# Why can I access an element I just erased from an stl vector in c++?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, erase

In this example, I create a vector with one integer in it and then I erase that integer from the vector. The size of the vector decreases, but the integer is still there! Why is the integer still there? How is it possible for a vector of size 0 to contain elements?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int agrc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(450);

    cout << "Before" << endl;
    cout << "Size: " << v.size() << endl;
    cout << "First element: " << (*v.begin()) << endl;
    v.erase(v.begin());
    cout << "After" << endl;
    cout << "Size: " << v.size() << endl;
    cout << "First element: " << *(v.begin()) << endl;

    return(0);
}
```

output:

```
Before
Size: 1
First element: 450
After
Size: 0
First element: 450
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC a vector doesn't release space unless specifically told to, so you're seeing an item which is still in its memory but not being tracked by the vector.  This is part of the reason why you're supposed to check the size first (the other being that if you never assigned anything, you'll be dereferencing a garbage pointer).

Comment: It is important to note that trying to access elements beyond the end of the vector (including previously existing but now deleted) elements is Undefined Behavior (i.e. an error), the implementation might crash your application if you are lucky, as that will help debug the issue. You cannot depend on this behavior at all.

Comment: @David: True, but in this case I would think that was obvious, and the OP was asking why it *didn't* dump core.

Answer (score 10):

You are invoking undefined behavior by dereferencing an invalid memory location. Normally, the heap manager will not immediately free the memory deleted using `delete` for efficiency purposes. However, that doesn't mean that you can access that memory location, heap manager can use this memory location for other purposes whenever it likes. So your program will behave unpredictably if you dereference a invalid memory location.

Comment: Except the question is about `vector::erase()`, not `delete`. Behaviour is still undefined, but it's because you're accessing an invalid object, not an invalid memory location.

Comment: Internally `vector::erase()` will call `delete` on the stored object, so it is undefined behavior for the same reason. `delete` is the reason the object is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

To start, don't count on it being this way across all systems.  How a vector works internally is **completely** implementation-dependent.  By dereferencing an invalid memory location, you're circumventing the behavior  that has been outlined in the documentation.
That is to say, you can **only** count on behavior working that is outlined in the STL docs.

The reason you can still access that memory location is because that particular implementation you are using doesn't immediately delete memory, but keeps it around for awhile(probably for performance purposes).  Another implementation could very well delete that memory immediately if the author so desired.

Answer (score 0):

It is just that the vector has not freed the memory, but kept it around for future use.

This is what we call "undefined behaviour"  There is no guarantee that it will work next time and it may easily crash the program on a future attempt.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

What are your compiler options?  I get a crash with the usual
options, with both of the compilers I regularly use (g++ and
VC++).  In the case of g++, you have to set some additional
options (-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG, I think) for this behavior; as far as
I can tell, it's the default for VC++.  (My command for VC++ was
just "cl /EHs bounds.cc".)

As others have said, it's undefined behavior, but with a good
compiler, it will be defined to cause the program to crash.

Comment: no options, just g++ a.cpp -o a... maybe -O4. You think that could change anything?

Comment: For g++ (and every other compiler I've ever used), you need a number of options for it to do anything serious.  I't highly recommend -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG, for example, unless you find it impacts too much on performance.